# Android: ¿Al llamar y cerrar un activity desde un fragment, el contexto del fragment es nulo?

Tags: android

Buen día.

Tengo un fragment que llama un activity, al cerrar el activity y volver a mi fragment el contexto es nulo ¿Como puedo solucionar esta situación?

[image: Esto es lo que me resulta al cerrar la activity, no tengo acceso al contexto ni a nada todo queda en nulo]

Esto es lo que me resulta al cerrar la activity, no tengo acceso al contexto ni a nada todo queda en nulo

Comment: Hola, si agregas código podremos ayudarte de forma mas acertada, saludos.

Comment: Agrega el código de como creas el fragmento y como lo mandas cargar.

Comment: Me di cuenta que en el metodo onResume (Al cerrrar el activity) de mi fragment, tenia todo el contexto, y con esto logre que el contexto no fuera nulo.

Comment: @devjav no solo de esa forma obtienes el contexto, si tienes un Fragment, este debe siempre estar sobre una Activity, por lo tanto para obtener el Contexto desde un Fragment usa getActivity(), revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

El contexto desde un `Fragment` lo puedes obtener mediante [`getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29).

> [`getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29), Regresa la Activity asociada al Fragment.
>   Activity es un Context *(Activity extiende de Context)*.

---

> Tengo un fragment que llama un activity, al cerrar el activity y
>   volver a mi fragment el contexto es nulo

Creo que el problema es la variable que tienes como Contexto, tal vez usas el contexto de la actividad que abriste y posteriormente cerraste, te sugiero obtener el contexto dentro del Fragmente mediante [`getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29).

Al obtener el contexto de esta forma obtendrás el contexto de la `Activity` asociada al `Fragment` cuyo valor no sería null.

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta para ver un poco mejor mi panorama